# GLIBC_2.27 not found when launching applications through Nautilus

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, ffmpeg, glibc

I have VSCode installed and never experienced this issue before, but now after I installed some web camera utilities and video conversion I seemed unable to launch VSCode from Nautilus.

**What works:**
Open a terminal directly and type `code`

**What doesn't work:**
Open Nautilus, right click any folder, open with Other application > VSCode.
Open Nautilus, right click any folder, open terminal here, type `code`

**Error message:**

```
code
/snap/code/25/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so)
/snap/code/25/usr/share/code/bin/../code: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so)
```

What is the root cause of this issue and how do I fix it ?

**Other information:**

```
ldconfig --version
ldconfig (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Andreas Jaeger.
```